# How determine Python script run from IDE or standalone

Tags: python-3.x

I've recently started learning python and am still a newbie.
How can I determine if my code run from IDE or run standalone?
My code is not imported so
`__name__ == "__main__"`  .
Someone suggested checking sys.executable name but I'm looking for a solution independent of the file name.

P.S: I create a standalone file with pyinstaller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a link to the page pyinstaller has on their site giving information about how to check the Run-Time information of your file: https://pyinstaller.org/en/stable/runtime-information.html

Basically it says to add the following code

```
import sys
if getattr(sys, 'frozen', False) and hasattr(sys, '_MEIPASS'):
    print('running in a PyInstaller bundle')
else:
    print('running in a normal Python process')
```

This should print the 'running in a PyInstaller bundle' message if it's all self contained and properly bundled, and it should print 'running in a normal Python process' if it's still running from your source code.

Comment: just want to check the code run in design-mode or runtime-mode. @Aproximate Knowledge

Comment: @see I updated my answer to hopefully be correct given your clarification. At the very least it now also includes a link to PyInstaller's page documenting how to get Run-Time information for your files! Hopefully this is what you're looking for!